# ssh tunnel to a friends computer

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I recently set up a laptop for the father of a friend.

Her father is not accompanied to linux and I would like to be able to log in to the computer remotely to help.

Usually I just log in using ssh. But that requires me to know the remote machines IP and an open port mapped from the router to the remote machine.

I'm afraid neither her nor her father are able to set up a dynamic DNS or port forwarding.

Can I use a ssh tunnel?

I have a linux based server which has a known address and open ports.

Thanks in advance

Markus

Comment: Try using a VPN, like [ZeroTier](https://www.zerotier.com/). You can then ssh from any other machine on the network to an IP assigned for her father's machine. Their free tier supports upto 100 clients. You probably won't be able to run X server applications due to bandwidth and latency limitations.

Comment: Well you can reverse SSH by having them initiate the connection to your server, if you like. Then just use it as a jump host. The basic answer to your question would be "yes."

Answer (score 0):

Native SSH Port Forwarding (Tunneling) on Windows 10
You need to find out how to use the built-in Windows 10 OpenSSH server to forward ports via an SSH tunnel. SSH port forwarding allows you to tunnel (forward) app ports from a local computer to a remote server and vice versa. Earlier SSH tunneling was used in Linux/Unix environment only, but today you can use it in Windows 10/Windows Server 2016 as well. Search Google for 'how to use an RDP connection through the SSH tunnel (TCP port 22) on Windows'.

SSH tunneling, is mostly used in the scenarios when you need to connect to a remote computer behind the firewall. For example, you have a Windows Server with only SSH port open (TCP 22). All other ports are blocked by a hardware firewall or Windows Firewall. Your task is to connect to the Windows Server using the RDP client. It seems impossible since Remote Desktop port 3389 is blocked by the firewall. However, you can use the port forwarding technique through the SSH tunnel.

Here are the typical usage scenarios of SSH tunneling:

Local TCP forwarding is a local port forwarding to a remote server;
Remote TCP forwarding is a remote port forwarding to a local computer;
Double SSH tunnel connects computers without any dedicated pubic IP addresses behind NAT through an SSH server (if OpenVPN solution is not applicable).
RDP Access Through SSH Tunnel (Local TCP Forwarding)
In this mode, you create a local TCP port on your computer. All connections to this port are forwarded to the specified port on a remote server via the SSH tunnel. You must create a local Port 8888, and the connection to it will be forwarded to the RDP port 3389 on a remote Windows computer. The general connection scheme is findable in google search or youtube.

To create an SSH tunnel using the built-in Windows 10 SSH client (is a part of Windows starting from Windows 10 1809 and Windows Server 2019), run this command:

ssh -L 8888:192.168.1.90:3389 root@192.168.1.90